# Setting number of gunicorn workers in django settings.py

Tags: django, gunicorn

I'm using gunicorn to run my django site locally when developing. I have gunicorn added under INSTALLED_APPS in my settings.py and I can call "python manage.py run_gunicorn" and gunicorn starts up and loads my site just fine. My problem is that I would like to run multiple workers with gunicorn and by default it only seems to be spawning one. I can also use "gunicorn_django --workers=2" and it fires 2 workers. Can I configure the default number of workers that are created when I call "python manage.py run_gunicorn" to be more than 1?

Machine specs:
Ubuntu 11.10 in Virtualbox instance
2 virtualized processors
1.5 gigs of ram

Comment: Have you figured out how to pass config arguments to `python manage.py run_gunicorn`?

Comment: @MichaelWaterfall - No I haven't tried that. Something like python manage.py run_gunicorn -workers=2?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `-c` command to specify a configuration file (written in python):

http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/configure.html#settings

Since this is a python file, you can `from django.conf import settings` and do

```
workers = settings.GUNICORN_WORKERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add:

```
run_gunicorn --workers=4
```

You can make the command a unix alias if you want to have the number of workers default to this.

Comment: I tried this out 'python ./manage.py run_gunicorn --workers=4 0.0.0.0:80' but unfortunately it does not work.

Comment: This worked with older versions of gunicorn (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gunicorn/0.6.4). It doesn't seem to work in the latest version, however.

Comment: Update: the above still works, but it needs to be at the end. (i.e. run_gunicorn unix:/sites/mysite/run/my.sock --workers=5 )

Answer (score 0):

You're not supposed to do `python manage.py run_gunicorn`. 

do `gunicorn project_name.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 10`

or do `python -m gunicorn project_name.wsgi -b 0.0.0.0:8000 -w 10`

if you're keen on using `manage.py` command read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/howto/custom-management-commands/) on how to create a custom management command, create when that uses the `subprocess` module's `Popen` method to call one of commands i've written above